# On click, refocus down to tab not functioning. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click, refocus down to tab not functioning. Any suggestions? I'm using jQuery of course.

Essentially, I want to refocus down to this tab and open the tab at the same time while refocusing to it.

My code is: [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5TRM/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Animates Scrolling
    function scrollToAnchor(aid){
        var divTag = $("div[name='"+ aid +"']");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top},'slow');
    }

    $("#ReadDescription").click(function() {
        scrollToAnchor('longdescreadmore');
    });

});
```

HTML, where I'm trying to focus to:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="readmore">
    <div name="longdescreadmore" id="longdescreadmore">[[DMI:Property name='LongDescription']][[/DMI:Property]]</div>
</div>
```

HTML, tab header:

```
 <li class="readmore"><a href="#readmore">Read More</a></li>
```

HTML, where the click action is taking place:

```
 <h2 id="ReadDescription" class="ReadDescription">Read More</h2>
```

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/S5TRM/1/

Comment: Odd, on my actual site, doesn't work at all. What in the world. I wonder if it's because that tab is the last tab in a series of tabs..

Comment: Are you sure the code is being reached at the proper time? As in located in the correct position?